# getting unstructured CSV-madness into order: does this make sense?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have logfiles in the file-format of csv. 
The vendor of the app it comes from wants to stick with it. 
MY goal is to build a logreader that does some highlighting and filtering.

The CSV looks ugly as hell, because it is not at all tidy, even if you put some work into it in Excel. A sample of that structure is attached.
Now, i've been pondering about the solution of this a while and came up with a kinda complex solution. But i don't like that solution. It feels too "special"

**But Let's look at what we have:** 
- The columns and their order are defined by a customizable view in the app.
So sometimes e.g. the date-column is first, could also be last, could be missing even.  The output is not in the correct order. Sometimes the DAte-coulmn contains the Details-Text. Sometimes a MAC. It's madness.

Edit: Here is how it can look when it's raw data:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=79649596476923658435

[image]

**So what i came up with is this:**
- read line1 of your csv, then you know the columns of that file.
- read a config-file that defines "detection-rules" for Columns with set names. So for instance you have a filter for a Colunm for Mac-addresses. One for IP-addresses and vice versa. The Columnns themself are predefined so this is at least possible.

- so you read the CSV-line2 and spilt that string to an array, loop through and check for each string if that string matches one of your filters.

Then - if you have a match - you loop through the array you created with the Column-titles (you read line1 of the CSV) 
The looping-instance increments a number up. 
Then you have another array with the same size as the array containing the titles. You put the found value in there (the incremented number represents the index you use in the new array)

This all probably sounds hard to understand so i wrote a bit of code to illustrate how i meant it. 
Am i missing something or is this the way to go with what i have ?

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load




    Dim Line1csv() As String = {"Date", "MAC"}

    Dim csvdata As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("tst.csv")

    For Each csvline In csvdata

        'lets split the line into pot. cell-values
        Dim Csvlinestr() As String = csvline.Split(",")

        'now lets loop through what we created and find out what it is
        For Each csvfielstr In Csvlinestr

            'ok lets ask what this field is
            Dim Csvlinetype As String = AskmeWhatitis(csvfielstr)
            'good lets say it told us that the result is title2
            'so where do we put it ? lets loop through the line1csv to find out the indx

            Dim found As Boolean = False
            Dim Indx As Integer = 0

            For Each l1csvstr In Line1csv
                If l1csvstr = Csvlinetype Then
                    found = True
                End If
                Indx += 1
            Next

            If found = True Then
                ' here we'd put it into our "sorted array that has the same size as the line1csv-array()
                ' the index used is sthe indx-variable we used above
            End If
        Next


    Next





End Sub


Public Function AskmeWhatitis(ByVal instr As String) As String
    ' this sub has a config-file that tells it what to search how and what the match will mean: does it mean its a MAC or date or whaterver 



    Return "truth"

End Function
```

End Class

Comment: You are asking us about data you have already processed (even if only by opening it in Excel).  2-3 lines of the raw text file would be better

Comment: " read line1 of your csv, then you know the columns of that file " - But the example you've given kind of gives the lie to that. Or something.

Comment: I agree, open the file in notepad and post as is the first few lines. It's entirely possible the problem only comes from non-standard delimiters, or the file having non-Windows line termination.

Comment: There are libraries that help you do this. You can use ADO.NET and query the columns out the CSV file with a SELECT-statement using a OLEDB Jet driver.

Comment: As they said it would be much easier if we could see the raw file that produced the image above.

Comment: Are you saying that line1 tells you the fields you will find in the data, but in line2, line3, etc, the fields can occur in any order? Eg the first column could contain Details, or Date or MAC address etc? So therefore you need to parse the input to work out which of the fields it could be??

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i have uploaded a slightly modified file (for data protection reasons)

Comment: It looks as if you may have embedded \n (line feed) in Details field. The fields appear to be in correct order but the embedded \n chars cause new lines to appear when they shouldn't. You might consider joining lines that do not end with a valid MAC address followed by a comma. Eg "Redistributable - x86 " ends line 4 - this line doesn't end with MAC address so join the next line to it. Line 5 ends ".20122". Again, not a MAC address so join the next line to it. Next line ends "1c770ebb43e5,". Aha, a real MAC address and we have true end of line.

Comment: Alternatively assume a logical line must start Ddd Mmm HH:mm:ss etc. Then join physical lines until you see a new logical line. There is some extraneous stuff (lines 13-19 and line 23). You could create a new column Unmatched and put it in that.

Comment: The big problem is that the logical lines not always start with a date. Sometimes they just write stuff without that data in it. They just insert stuff from different routines. That is also the reason why some columns are not filled at all. Some lines have no mac at the end, because the routine us eg. just doing sw inventory.

Comment: Like @JohnD said, you have non-standard line and/or field separators in your file. the columns not lining up correctly in Excel is a dead give-away. Open the file with something like NotePad++, turn on "Show all characters", look if there are any offending ones, remove those with VB... Done!

Comment: There are several entries in there that dont match the "format".  The 7th record has that long antivirus message after MAC and BEFORE the next date with no comma.  Then another after that about the `SecureConnector` which is out of place in the same way.  Otherwise it maps in sets of 6 nicely.  Either it is corrupt, they screwed up or you messed it up sanitizing it for our viewing

Comment: The "format" is just very bad, and irregular. The CSV standard allows for text qualifiers in these cases. The company that makes this software needs to correct their format, either by wrapping fields with quotes (") as a text qualifier, or by encoding the fields so that they contain no errant \n. There is also the issue of the missing 7th field. Each line should not be ending in a comma, or the first line should have an additional field that will always be empty. This format is not proper CSV.